# get model triggering events in collection

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a collection of models in Backbone. One model is triggering a custom event, that I can catch, listening to the collection. What is the best way to find out, which model triggered the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the model ID with your custom event like this:

```
yourModel.trigger('customEvent', yourModel.get('id'))
```

and on the callback that catch the custom event you'll get the id as a parameter:

```
yourCallback: function(id) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You could simply pass 'this' or YourModel as argument for trigger. This way you won't have to do: model=collection.get(id)